# my code is right but Lua replace doesn't working (:gsub)

Tags: string, replace, lua

Hello I am trying to replace a specific text to "" and my code doesn't working. I just don't know why my code not working

```
b = 'Just testing.<script>window.location.replace("http://google.com");</script>'
print(b)
b = b:gsub('<script>window.location.replace("http://google.com");</script>', "")
print(b)
```

out 1: Just testing.window.location.replace("http://google.com");
out 2: Just testing.window.location.replace("http://google.com");

I tried `b = string.gsub(b,'<script>window.location.replace("http://google.com");</script>',"")` too but its doesn't worked either

I am working in FiveM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `(` and `)`, in a lua pattern they are recognized as special character. you can escape them using `%`

```lua
b = 'Just testing.<script>window.location.replace("http://google.com");</script>'
print(b)
b = b:gsub('<script>window.location.replace%("http://google.com"%);</script>', "")
print(b)
```

For more infomration on lua patter you can look at these resources:

[Understanding Lua Patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)

[20.1 – Pattern-Matching Functions](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html)

[20.2 – Patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)

Comment: Hello thanks for helping but your code is not working either and I don't enough english for understand this documentation could you please send me another code something work

Comment: hello it was my bad your code is working sorry for that

Comment: @Mordexx what is your native language? i might be able to find better resources that can help you specifically

Comment: you probly gonna can't find out because my language is not familiar. its Turkish. Thanks for helping <3

Comment: yeah...  I think you are right, sorry.

Comment: no problem thanks for helping you are awesome!